# Updating entire ObservableCollection doesn't notify Binding control

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` in my `ViewModel`, that should get its values from a json file, as follows:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    RecordList = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
}
public void ReadJsonFile(string FileName)
{
    if (!FileName.ToUpper().EndsWith(".JSON")) return;
    String JSONString = File.ReadAllText(FileName);
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    RecordList = ser.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<Record>>(JSONString);
}
```

The problem is that the binding control (`DataGrid`) gets updated only if items are added or removed, and doesn't get updated when the entire collection is changed, as seen above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> doesn't get updated when the entire collection is changed, as seen above

That's because the binding is to *prior* reference exposed in the `RecordList` property.

The following line creates a *new* object on the `RecordList` property

```
RecordList = ser.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<Record>>(JSONString);
```

Now you have two `ObservableCollection<>` in memory.  The `DataGrid` is still bound to the original list.

Consider replacing the code with:

```
RecordList.Clear(); // don't create new, merely clear-and-append

foreach (var item in ser.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<Record>>(JSONString)) 
{
   RecordList.Add(item);
}
```

...or maybe:

```
RecordList.Clear(); // don't create new, merely clear-and-append
ser.Deserialize<List<Record>>(JSONString).ForEach (x = > RecordList.Add(x));
```

Doing so this way will ensure all change notifications are fired.

Comment: @AviranKatz You're welcome good sir.  This same issue happened to me ;)